# ";" folder name as directory path java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, runtime-error, directory

I was trying to have all my projects in a folder named ";" and they all stop from running, as soon as i changed it back they where perfectly fine.

Is there any way to run programs in a path like this:

```
D:\Desktop\;\program\
```

tip: this makes the following run time error:  "Error: Could not find or load main class {class name}" regardless of if the program is a simple hello world or a complicated calculation program.

Comment: why would someone want to name a folder `;`?

Comment: Why oh why would you want to name your folder `;`? Surely your problem is not one that needs solving. You can solve your problem by naming the folder `semicolon` instead of `;`.

Comment: if you want to run it from the terminal, try to enter the whole path in double quotes. what platform are you on?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file

Comment: To all you commenters saying you shouldn't have ";" as a folder name, you should either point at the Java documentation that says you shouldn't name your folders ";" or else don't say that. Anyway, I've tried it with a folder named `"C:\Users\dodgy\;\program"` and it worked successfully.

Comment: @Bohemian i was wondering the possibilities of java and windows, thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException thank you for understanding the situation, c:\users\... is an exception which i have tried and worked, the problem was on the desktop folder (which i have positioned in my other drive ( D:\ )

Comment: @kai what does this link tell us? It just confirms that the semicolon is NOT listed in the "forbidden characters".... There are still people around who tell us that a file name should not contain blanks, but since Windows 95 even Microsoft Windows uses blanks in standard file names (e.g. "Program Files"). The semicolon is not forbidden, so the question is valid - even if it's probably a scientific question and not a daily problem.

Comment: @kai that was exactly my point of view, as i searched through the forbidden characters and the list of paths and directories ended, there was not a single line referring to “;” being a non valid or exceptional character in java, or windows. This will not interfere with my programs, but i was curious that what is causing the problem.

Comment: @ChristophBimminger so question answerd: you can. That this question exists however is reason enough to not do it(the op seems to run in some problems). And because you mention it, yes spaces in filenames are maybe not as good as ";" but nevertheless a great way to create unecessary problems(a file that doesn't show up in a listing or fails loading is amazing regarding usabality)

Comment: @sam what is causing the problem is not that you can't have the character in a file(you can even have character not allowed according to that listing). The problem is that a filename is something, that is used to work with files. So if one uses your filename with a ";" with something that interprets that as a separator(which is not that uncommon) that person runs into a problem. (be it a distorted view, a parser that fails or be it simple an irritated user ....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java itself (in my case Oracle Java 8) does not have an issue with folders named with a semicolon (;). Even if it is a sub folder of Desktop, it works.

Test it the following way:

- open a commandline (cmd)
- navigate to the directory or path that contains the semicolon:
  `cd "C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\;\program"`
- run the java program:
  `java <MainClass>`

if it does not work, check if you defined your class inside a package (code assumes your class is in "default package", and the compiled .class file is stored in the ;\program subfolder of Desktop:

```
C:\Users\Christoph\Desktop\;\program>dir
 Volume in Laufwerk C: hat keine Bezeichnung.
 Volumeseriennummer: 366D-F05B

 Verzeichnis von C:\Users\Christoph\Desktop\;\program

05.03.2019  23:50    <DIR>          .
05.03.2019  23:50    <DIR>          ..
05.03.2019  23:50               534 HelloWorld.class
               1 Datei(en),            534 Bytes
               2 Verzeichnis(se), 69.522.284.544 Bytes frei

C:\Users\Christoph\Desktop\;\program>java HelloWorld
Hello World!

C:\Users\Christoph\Desktop\;\program>
```

Comment: ".java" file is in default src package. using cd to open the folder ";" does not work, it does if whole path is entered between double quotations. compiled file did not work and i got the same error via command prompt. i have tried compiling the file into same folder (not the compile folder that intellij created) by javac via cmd, it compiled perfectly. 
when ran the compiled file with java via cmd i didnt get the error.

thus the error lies within intellij path of file (its not using double quotations).

Comment: So, intelliJ does not provide support for that kind of folders...
How did you "cd"? when doublequoting the parameter (cd ";") it worked in my case.

Comment: cd “desktop\;\program\src”